# Проблема с EasyTabs на Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю свой браузер на основе движка Google Chrome, Chromium. И решил в качестве вкладок использовать EasyTabs. Не знаем как контролировать название в вкладке. Помогите пожалуйста, если никак, то подскажите, как заменить EasyTabs и чем? Желательно с гайдом.

Comment: `Caption` не работает?

Comment: @4per не могу найти, можно пример пожалуйста как задавать?

Comment: Я просто глянул исходники и там есть свойство Caption у вкладки. Сам я никогда не использовал эту либу. Был бы рад, если бы вы проверили и отписались о результате.

Comment: а где вы нашли? EasyTabs.????